# Flutter How to listen variable from other class

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to listen variable from other class in flutter, so always to know if the app has internet connection 
I have the streamcontroller in checknetwork.dart and listen in home.dart
I dont get anything at print statement

CheckNetwork.dart

```
class NetworkCheck {
  var streamController = StreamController();

  Future<bool> check() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      streamController.sink.add(true);
        streamController.close();

      return true;
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      streamController.sink.add(true);
      streamController.close();

      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  dynamic checkInternet(Function func) {
    check().then((internet) {
      if (internet != null && internet) {
        func(true);
      }
      else{
        func(false);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Home.dart

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home>{
Future _checkNetwork() async {

  NetworkCheck networkcheck = NetworkCheck();

  networkcheck.streamController.stream.listen((data) {
  print('Got! $data');
  });
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you need a State Management solution. Have a look at ScopedModel, Provider, BLoC or Redux for Flutter. There are others. The specific problem you are trying to solve is tricky, because showing any kind of SnackBar or other type of popup triggered from a different class requires you to have the `context` of the current view the user is in.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so will the above code I cannot listen the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a state management System to get the stream controller accessible to all classes and it would be the efficient way , but if you still want your current code to work than call check method of NetworkCheck class before listening to the Stream .

So modify your home.dart like this:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home>{
Future _checkNetwork() async {

  NetworkCheck networkcheck = NetworkCheck();

 //this will provide value in your stream.
  networkcheck.check();

  networkcheck.streamController.stream.listen((data) {
  print('Got! $data');
  });
  }
```